# JPA: How to convert LocalDateTime to LocalDate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, named-query, localdate

How could I use @NamedQuery to get a coloumn as LocalDate type which is defined LocalDateTime type. How can i do it?

Comment: You retrieve the field, and convert it in Java! Which is nothing to do with JPA

Answer (score 17):

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
      LocalTime time = LocalTime.now();
      LocalDateTime dateTimeFromDateAndTime = LocalDateTime.of(date, time);

      System.out.println(dateTimeFromDateAndTime);

      LocalDate dateFromDateTime = LocalDateTime.now().toLocalDate();
      LocalTime timeFromDateTime = LocalDateTime.now().toLocalTime();

      System.out.println(dateFromDateTime);

      System.out.println(timeFromDateTime);
 }
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. Thanks

Comment: The question was how he can convert LocalDateTime to LocalDate inside the query.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that by `a column which is defined LocalDateTime type` you have declared an entity with a LocalDateTime field.

If you want to make the date conversion on the database, i think you will have to use a native query.
If you don't mind making the conversion in java, I see two options:

- Adding a converter on your entity field so that it can be a LocalDate binding a timestamp (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Convert.html)
- Adding a @Transient getter so that you can make the conversion in the entity class.